# how to pass date parameter in openquery statement

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2005, openquery

I have one procedure

```
Create procedure [dbo].[daily_stats]
@date datetime, @grouping varchar(150)
as

select callid,campaignid,dnis,anidigits,callstarttime,totalcalltime,agenttalktime,agentid,abandon,queuewaittime,calltype,call_acw,datestamp,bill_flag,
queueid,queuename,calldelayed, callholdtime, shortcall,ctr_name,role_name,team_name,callhold_times,agent_fullname,xferto,timeafterxfer,
obcallids,obcalls,obtime,orgname, getdate() as ImportedDate

into #tempid7

from openquery(orapr2, 'select * from sp_calldetail
where trunc(callstarttime) >= trunc(sysdate-1) and abandon in (0,1) and (upper(campaignid) in (''SYNAPSE'', ''SYNAPSECALLBACK'') or campaignid like ''ME%'')')
```

I want to pass `@date` value at `trunc(sysdate-1)`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> how to pass date parameter in openquery statement

Instead of using `openquery` function you could try this solution

```
EXEC LINKEDSVR_BUH_03.TestUPSERT.dbo.Customer_Select @pCustomerID = 2
EXEC LINKEDSVR_BUH_03..dbo.Customer_Select @pCustomerID = 2 -- It uses default database (see Catalog property for linked server)
```

or this

```
EXEC (N'TestUPSERT.dbo.Customer_Select ?', 2) AT LINKEDSVR_BUH_03
EXEC (N'dbo.Customer_Select ?', 2) AT LINKEDSVR_BUH_03 -- It uses default database (see Catalog property for linked server)
                            ^----- parameter placeholder
                                ^----- parameter value
```

Comment: thanq for your response Bogdan, but my procedure is in sqlserver, and orapr2 is located on oracle server. so how do i read sql server parameter in oracle.

Comment: "[...]how do i read sql server parameter in oracle[...]". Please rephrase.

Comment: i have to pass @date parameter for trunc(sysdate-1) date parameter is in sqlserver database, and trunc(sysdate-1) is in oracle server.

Comment: help me for that, i really struggle by this since yesterday.

Comment: "[...]for trunc(sysdate-1) date parameter[...]" TRUNC and SYSDATE are functions not parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to convert the date-time to Oracle format - for example :

`TO_DATE(''''' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @From, 120) + ''''',''''YYYY-MM-DD'''')`

Otherwise it returned the error - Invalid Month